# AsyncTask constructor without super() invocation

Tags: android, constructor, android-asynctask

What could happen if i don't call super() inside an AsyncTask constructor? i've always coded it without super invocation, but on some developers.android tutorials, super is used

Comment: without super(), code in AsyncTask constructor is not called (see https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/os/AsyncTask.java#L281)

Comment: i've always omitted super call, and constructor works always well!

Comment: You should better learn Java before asking about AsyncTask. It's constructor behaves just as any other class.

Answer (score 4):

In java, the default constructor `super()` is *always called implicitly*. That means that **it makes no difference whether you call it or not**. It will be called anyways.

From the [java language specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/classes.html#8.8.7):

> If a constructor body does not begin with an explicit constructor invocation and the constructor being declared is not part of the primordial class Object, then the constructor body is implicitly assumed by the compiler to begin with a superclass constructor invocation "super();", an invocation of the constructor of its direct superclass that takes no arguments.